# How to create Databricks Cluster using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to create Databricks Cluster using ARM template. Is it supported ?
If supported kindly provide some references.Following is the code to create Databricks workspace using ARM template

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces",
      "name": "[parameters('workspaceName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('pricingTier')]"      
      },
      "tags": {
        "ComponentID": "[parameters('tagComponentID')]",
        "Env": "[parameters('tagEnv')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "ManagedResourceGroupId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', variables('managedResourceGroupName'))]"        
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DataBricks is using a separate API, you cant use ARM template to create a cluster. The only API call exposed in ARM is creating a workspace.

Comment: Thanks for your input

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, creation of Data Bricks cluster is currently unsupported.

The same feedback shown here -> https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909463-azure-databricks/suggestions/35257819-expose-api-key-during-arm-deployment was shared directly with the responsible Azure feature team.

I recommend navigating to the above link and clicking the vote button to raise visibility and priority on this (or) post your feedback and idea to have ARM template for Data Bricks cluster creation under https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909463-azure-databricks.

For now, as a workaround you may automate Data Bricks cluster creation using Cluster REST API https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/clusters.html#create.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!! :)

Comment: Thanks for your input